# How should I handle the fd passed to fdopen or fdopendir if the function fails?

Tags: c, error-handling, posix

If I have the following:

```
const int fd = open("somedir", O_DIRECTORY);
if (fd == -1) {
    return FAIL;
}
DIR *const dir = fdopendir(fd);
if (!dir) {
    // close(fd) OR NOT?
    return FAIL;
}
// Do stuff with dir
return closedir(dir) ? FAIL : SUCCESS;
```

What is the state of the `fd` passed should `fdopendir` or `fdopen` fail? Should I close it, risking extraneous system calls at best or undefined behavior at worst if `fd` is invalidated by the call, or should I not call `close()`, and risk leaking resources/open file descriptors? I could not find docs that specify how to handle the `fd` passed to these functions should the functions fail.

Comment: The [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopendir.3p.html) reads: "*Upon successful return from fdopendir(), the file descriptor is under the control of the system*". I think it would be reasonable and safe to read that as the caller still controlling the fd if the function fails. And there's always reading the open source code to see what major implementations do.

Comment: @kaylum So until further notice, yes use `close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839647/how-should-i-handle-the-fd-passed-to-fdopen-or-fdopendir-if-the-function-fails#comment125233748_70839647):

The manual reads (emphasis mine):

> Upon **successful** return from `fdopendir()`, the file descriptor is under the control of the system

**Successful** implies that what follows does not apply to an unsuccessful return. Therefore one **should** use `close()` after an unsuccessful `fdopendir()` return.